# Insert a record with a date from a jDateChooser and a null for a number in Oracle using Java

Tags: java, oracle, date, insert, null

It's the first time I've posted here, but i'm really in a trouble.

I have the table `EMPLOYEES`:

> EMPLOYEE_ID  NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
>
> FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20)
>
> LAST_NAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)
>
> EMAIL                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)
>
> PHONE_NUMBER                                       VARCHAR2(20)
>
> HIRE_DATE                                 NOT NULL DATE
>
> JOB_ID                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
>
> SALARY                                             NUMBER(8,2)
>
> COMMISSION_PCT                                     NUMBER(2,2)
>
> MANAGER_ID                                         NUMBER(6)
>
> DEPARTMENT_ID                                      NUMBER(4)

and I need to insert the next record:

```sql
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (307,'Alfredo','Garcia','alfredgad','222222', TO_DATE('07-JUN-1994', 'dd-MON-yyyy'),'AC_ACCOUNT',8300,NULL,205,110);
```

I have the next code:

My class Conexion

```java
package nomina;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Conexion {

    static Connection conn=null;
    static Statement st=null;
    static ResultSet rs=null;


    static String bd="ORCL";
    static String login="XXXX";
    static String password="XXX";
    static String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL";

    public static Connection Enlace(Connection conn)throws SQLException    {
        try {
         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
         conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e )
        {
            System.out.print("Clase no encontrada");
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public static Statement sta(Statement st)throws SQLException    {
        conn=Enlace(conn);
        st=conn.createStatement();
        return st;
    }
    public static ResultSet EnlEst(ResultSet rs)throws SQLException    {
       st=sta(st);
       rs=st.executeQuery("select * from employees");
        return rs;
    }


}
```

The method where I'm trying to insert the record:

```java
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


        int id = 0;
        double salario = 0;
        int jefe = 0;
        int depto = 0;
        String nombre = "", apellidos = "", correo = "", telefono = "", puesto = "";

        id = Integer.parseInt(jTextIdEmpleado.getText());
        apellidos = jTextNom.getText();
        apellidos = jTextApe.getText();
        correo = jTextMail.getText();
        telefono = jTextTel.getText();
        puesto = jTextPuesto.getText();
        salario = Double.parseDouble(jTextSalario.getText());
        jefe = Integer.parseInt(jTextIdJefe.getText());
        depto = Integer.parseInt(jTextDep.getText());

        try {
            // main miconexion = new main();
            conn = Conexion.Enlace(conn);
            Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
            try {

                sta.executeQuery("INSERT INTO employees VALUES (307,'Alfredo','Garcia','alfredgad','222222', TO_DATE('07-JUN-1994', 'dd-MON-yyyy'),'AC_ACCOUNT',8300,NULL,205,110)");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("error");
                sta.close();
            }
            String sqlinsertar = "insert into employees (employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement psta = conn.prepareStatement(sqlinsertar);
            psta.setInt(1, id);
            psta.setString(2, nombre);
            psta.setString(3, apellidos);
            psta.setString(4, correo);
            psta.setString(5, telefono);
            psta.setDate(6, (Date) jDateChooser1.getDate());//Probar por separado
            psta.setString(7, puesto);
            psta.setDouble(8, salario);
            psta.setNull(9, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            psta.setInt(10, jefe);
            psta.setInt(11, depto);
            psta.executeUpdate();
            psta.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro Guardado Satisfactoriamente");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getCause());
        }
    }
```

But when I execute it, it doesn't work and the console only says "null". I think the problem is either the date or the null but I've been trying for a week and I haven't worked it out.

I hope someone can tell my what the problem is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The exception's stacktrace will tell you what line is null, and then you can use a debugger or println statements to find out which variable is null. You will want to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should inspect the line carefully that throws the exception**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: Oh, and change `System.out.println(e.getCause()); ` for `e.printStackTrace()` as it will give you much more useful information.

Comment: I've already printed all the variables and none is null, i think the way i'm setting the date or the null may be wrong but i really have no idea

Comment: Thanks for the tip i made the change you suggested and it says the next error

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

It seems i was right about the date, could somebody tell me how i should save the date?

Comment: **What line causes the exception**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding,

> next error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

It looks like JFileChooser returns a java.util.Date and what you need is a java.sql.Date, a class that inherits from java.util.Date and that is used by SQL databases as a Date type. I don't see any copy constructor, but perhaps you can use the constructor that takes a long parameter to convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date.

So what if you change this:

```
psta.setDate(6, (Date) jDateChooser1.getDate());//Probar por separado
```

to this:

```
java.util.Date utilDate = (java.util.Date) jDateChooser1.getDate();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
psta.setDate(6, sqlDate);
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!!

It worked perfect!

Now you helped me it looks obvious and i fell kind of idiot hehe I had been trying to figure it out for a long. You just saved me

Comment: @AlfredoGarcia: You're welcome. The key is to read the error message critically since it essentially spells out your problem.